# Odd markings on a mesh

Tags: mesh

I am new to Blender 3.3, I'm trying to put together a creature (using scripting rather than GUI) and it's all fine except for some weird markings.

[image: creature]

The creature's body is essentially a `primitive_cylinder_add` then a `primitive_uv_sphere_add` at each end, joined together with a *Union* modifier.

However, at the bottom edge of the original cylinder and up the side there's a darker patch and I can't understand how that comes about.

In *Wireframe mode* it looks normal but in *Solid* and other modes it has the problem.

Can anyone tell me what might cause this and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Most likely a result of the boolean operation - try select all > M (merge), and select by distance to get rid of any duplicate verts, then try Ctrl+Shift+N to recalculate the normals (outside).

Comment: Thanks very much... I was confused by your keyboard options until I realised you were in Edit mode... but I found using 'join' was a lot simpler than my boolean union and adding auto-smooth resolved the issue